# Filter results on index view in GridView Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have a set of 'clients' and they are displayed in a GridView. 'Clients' can not be deleted by the average user, only marked for deletion. However I would like it so they are not displayed in the list once they are marked for deletion.

I am using Yii2, and the soft deletion table contains has three columns that concern the data 'foreign_table', 'foreign_column' and 'foreign_value'. It is set up like so as I do not want to delete data from the 'Clients' table unless it is needed.

How would I go about filtering the results of the GridView?

Would I use $model->search?

Comment: Have you been able to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use `$model->search` to filter the result, provided that the following steps are already done:

1. You have a means of flagging rows marked for deletion: `state` or `status`.
2. In the `search()` method of the Model represented by `$model` you specify the criteria used to filter the result by using: `$criteria->condition = 'status=1 OR status=2';`.

Depending on your database and how you have decided to flag or marked-as-deleted, you may have to modify `$criteria`. You may even chose to use `$criteria->with` to include foreign tables.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table where you save references to items that should be considered as deleted.

I think it could be reasonable to override find() of the Client class since there could be many cases where you want to ignore the marked-as-deleted clients. If so you could write the appropiate query in find(). As a nice side effect the GridView will show only the not marked-as-deleted clients automatically.

To get the marked-as-deleted clients you would need an extra methode, of course, if this is needed at all (you could want to delete them in the db directly and you don't need php code for this). But most of the time you don't need them. So you could filter them out by overriding the find method.